# Android emulation on intel

Tags: windows, performance, android-emulator, vmware-workstation

I will be developing (soon) on Android.
(I want to write a tiny business app. for managing customer groups)

I'm working on Win7, and according to you, what is the "best" target platform to work with ?
An android emulator with `HAXM` driver or a `VMWare workstation` with an android image ?

Comment: what type of application you are about to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using either a native Windows 7 or Mac environment for developing with the HAXM emulator.